# Django Model's styling convention within field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm curious as to what the proper styling is within a Django model. The documentation provides examples like so:

```
Do this:

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

Don’t do this:

class Person(models.Model):
    FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Last_Name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

But what I'm curious is what to do when there's a lot of information within the field such as:

```
class example(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=true, help_text=blahblahblahblahblahblah, related_name='related name example')
```

Is it appropriate to leave this long one-liner chunk of code, even when it reaches the line limit, or is there a proper way to do it?

Here's what I've been doing, which tends to look good at times, but bad during others:

```
class example(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, 
        blank=true, 
        help_text=blahblahblahblahblahblah, 
        related_name='related name example'
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much hit it on the head. Best thing to do is put each argument as its own line.

```
class example(models.Model): 
  first_name = models.CharField(
    max_length=20, 
    blank=true,
    help_text='blahblahblahblahblahblah',
    related_name='related name example'
  )
```